# LEXUS ES300 '99

Tags: battery, ignition, alternator, lexus

Ok so im having a problem that been happening for about 3 weeks. At one time we were at the movie drive in and my car died after 10min. Lights were all coming on and it would make several clicking sounds when you tried to turn it over. Did it again an hour later. Had to get a jump by movie workers (twice). Then it happened a few days later. We thought it was my alternator. Switched it out since i had warranty. Still the same. Thought it was my battery but it had 100% charge. Changed the terminals and it seemed to be the problem. Til yesterday... It was dying on us just sitting at pizza hut waiting for our food. We got it home as soon as we did it died and didnt turn on. We got a jump several hours later.. On our way to my moms it died at a stop light. Tried turning it over but the lights were dimmed out almost completely and it wasnt even making that clicking noise. Got a jump and as soon as i put it in R it died again. Got a jump let it sit n charge a bit and gt the car home. Now it turns on like nothing happened. **while at pizza hut.. Stepping on the gas and lettin it go the battery light would come on but if we didnt the light didnt show** SOMEONE please help!

Comment: How did you check to see if your battery was "100% charged"?

Comment: Took it to autozone

Comment: Does the alternator squeal at all when you first start it up?

Comment: No it doesnt do that either.

Comment: When was the last time the serpentine belt was replaced?

Comment: That i actyally dont know. Everyone keeps saying it something eletrical or one the wires or  something wet?

Answer (score 1):

I think there may be one or two things happening here (but this is more of a gut check than anything):

1. The serpentine belt is worn out, causing the battery not to charge the battery correctly. Usually if the belt is getting worn out, it will cause a chirping sound when it slips, but if the belt is worn and glazed, it could be slipping without you even knowing it, causing a loss in electrical charging ability, and thus allowing your battery to go flat. The jump and subsequent running at a normal level allows it to recharge.
2. The spring in the tensioner may be weak, causing the same issue as described above. I'm not sure on your specific vehicle, but there could be a tension gauge consisting of an arrow which will point inside a range. This will show if the belt has stretched, but will also show if the spring is weak.

Considering what you said about the dash lights coming on after a rev, I'm thinking scenario #2 is the most likely. This indicates to me the belt may be slipping across the alternator after a rev, which does not allow for proper charging.

Comment: Well im about to try n drive it across town bcuz my baby daddy is my mechanic. So ill let him know wat u posted... Hopefully ill make it there.